# Index SELECT MAX with WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-indexes, sql-server-2022

I know that this question was asked many times, but I could not find an explicit answer when there is a WHERE clause as well, and this is very important for me since I will have table with Millions of records.

If I have:

```sql
SELECT MAX (SomeINTvalue)
FROM tbTest
WHERE Filter1 = SomeVARCHAR32value
```

What index is best to create?

Also, if I use:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 
       SomeINTvalue
FROM tbTest
WHERE Filter1 = SomeVARCHAR32value
ORDER BY SomeINTvalue DESC
```

will it be better and what index to use in this case?

I researched many posts but I could not find an answer that considers WHERE clause (and these specific data types)

Comment: I suggest a non-clustered index on SomeVARCHAR32value, SomeINTvalue. Either query should perform well with this index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX tbTest (SomeVARCHAR32value, SomeINTvalue DESC)
```

You may want to add `INCLUDE` columns also, depending on what other queries you are running.

Both queries will probably end up with the same plan if you have that index in place.

Comment: I don't believe `DESC` is needed with the equality predicate on the leading column since the plan will include backward ordering for the seek predicate in the plan to touch the single row.

Comment: Just in case a parallel plan is being used in any other query: you can't do a parallel backwards scan. I seem to remember a cardinality estimation bug also if the index order isn't the same as the scan order.